# Fetching data from row N+M, N+2M,... when N changes

Tags: indexing, google-sheets

My Google spreadsheet has webpage data imported with IMPORTDATA() on Sheet1. The data of interest are 20 pcs of 12-row deep posts starting at row N (e.g. row 123). Unfortunately, N changes each week or so.

Today I just use 20 hardcoded formulas that copy the data of interest to Sheet2 (e.g. =Sheet1!A123), but each time N changes I need to re-code all these 20 copying formulas on Sheet 2.

I'd prefer a method using e.g. Indexing or Offset formulas, where I would only need to change one "starting index" value when N changes in the webpage. Help would be much appreciated!

EDIT : Hi, thanks for your interest, sorry for delay. So this is the data structure of my Google spreadsheet. The source data can be considered a product list or similar.

Sheet1: 
A1 =IMPORTDATA (url)
A2 to A122 
A123 product 1 name
A124 product 1 price
A125 to A132... other product 1 data
A133 product 2 name
A134 product 2 price
A135 to A142... other product 2 data
A143 product 3 name....
... and so on up to product 20.

On Sheet2 I then want the following result:
A1 product 1 name
A2 product 1 price
A3 product 2 name
A4 product 2 price. 
... and so on.

The problem is that the "uninteresting preamble data" in the beginning changes in length (number of rows) every now and then.

Comment: Did you have a look at OFFSET?

Comment: can you share a sample sheet - its pretty simple but need to see how you have it laid out in order to share the answer that will work for you